# IBM Watson api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com’s server IP address could not be found?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I start learning data science in IBM and I enroll in the course where we had to join in IBM cloud (lite) and then to create Watson studio(lite). I just followed the document and after creating Watson studio (lite) I got this error:

> api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com’s server IP address could not be found

It prevent me from seing the button "Get start" which I must click on

I tried to see solution but I didn't find anything and also I talked with watson in chatbox you provide support but the solution watson give didn't help me.

Link to course: 
https://developer.ibm.com/digitalnation/africa/skills/innovator-predict-employee-turnover-using-ibm-watson-studio/?module=02.03

For more info see my screenshot: ["click here" to see the screen shot i take it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyKmq.png)

Comment: Welcom to Stackoverflow! Not sure what you are doing and you get the error. The address / URL should exist as you can see here: https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/ and https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/faq.html#regions. The support must be able to help you.

Comment: it didn't fix my problem please see the photo , also this link give me the same error message in the photo : [link](https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/) and other link i see it but i cant see any support of my case , it show how to use watson app  but there are nothing about how to fix the problem that prevent me to use it.

Comment: sorry i mean Watson studio(lite) this service IBM provide for  digital learner .

Answer (score 1):

### Investigation

- I am unable to reproduce the issue.
- The **Watson Studio Instance Dashboard** loads successfully for me in the **London** data center.
- I highly suspect that your current web browser settings might be preventing the iframe'd content area from loading.

### Suggested Follow-up Actions

- (a) Try disabling your **Ad blocker** and reloading the page (ad blockers are known to block content from loading in iframes).
- (b) Try loading the page in a **new incognito window** (this will disable all browser extensions).
- (c) Try loading the page in another web browser (e.g. Firefox, Edge, Safari).
- (d) Try clearing your cookies for the **cloud.ibm.com** domain and reloading the page.
- (e) In your web browser, type *Control+Shift+J* (on Windows) or *Command+Option+J* (on Mac) to open the **Developer Tools** and take a screenshot of any errors you see in the **Console** tab (and post it back here).

  - Reference: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts
- (f) Try visiting the **direct URL** below to see if the page loads.

### Direct URL

- https://api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/dsx-service-broker/ui/console?plan_id=40073cbd-2d60-4a65-a32d-3b1d11794cc6

### Work-around

- Go directly to the **Watson Studio Registration Page** (which is the URL for the **Get Started** button)
- https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/registration/steptwo?redirectIfAccountExists=True&apps=watson_studio

Comment: i tried  all solution from A to F  nothing solve  , A) i did it nothing change error still,b)i open it in new tab and the addblock wasn't work nothing  nothing happen and still get the error  ,c)i open it from firefox and Microsoft Edge still with the error , e) i did it and only see white window or (box) in the left of the side but there was no error ,f) i visit it open with error Exactly the same error of the image i provide in the question . thank you but this answer is useless :( :'(

Comment: Notice  : my location is in (Cairo \ Egypt) not (United Kingdom \ London) i dont know if this will help you to come with solution or no but you now know that my location is different  -Notice : the course only click on create and it didn't give any info about the different loc .                                                                                                                        
, also i tried to open it from another device (my mobile) with open the location in mobile and i dont have adblock in my chrome of mobile  also tried to use firefox  nothing change :'(

Comment: @amAhmed 
Thanks for the additional information. Your location (Egypt) is definitely relevant. We've had a number of users (only) from Egypt report similar network connectivity issues; but, we haven't been able to ascertain or diagnose the underlying problem. I recommend following Jeff Sloyer's instructions below. We may need you to create an official IBM Support Ticket in order to investigate further. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `dig api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com` or `nslookup api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com`?  I am guessing its an issue with your DNS provider on your current network.  Can you try another network or wifi connection? For reference here is the `nslookup` I just did with it.

```
nslookup api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com
Server:     10.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:    10.xxx.xxx.xxx#53

Non-authoritative answer:
api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com    canonical name = api.watson-data-prod-lon.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud.
api.watson-data-prod-lon.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud   canonical name = watson-data-prod-lon.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud.
Name:   watson-data-prod-lon.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud
Address: 158.175.100.214
Name:   watson-data-prod-lon.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud
Address: 158.176.125.222
Name:   watson-data-prod-lon.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud
Address: 141.125.66.126
```

Comment: "Can you try another network or wifi connection?" -> i tried , nothing change ,                         also i check out the  dig api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com and nslookup api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com by copy and past in URL and they work and give me almost the same result  first result is watson-Ibm link which is the same in both and a lot of result other results but yeah it run . still the watson studio error exist  :'(         
thank you

Answer (score 0):

try using vpn supporting browser like opera it worked with me since I'm from Egypt and had the same error